# Add OpenCV in android SDK

Tags: opencv, sdk, android

**What I want?**

I want to create a SDK with the help of **openCV-android-sdk**.

**What i tried?**

I did get SDK but resulting SDK is very heavy as it include complete OpenCV. but i want to reduce the size of SDK like it happens in application scenario as giving large size SDK is not possible in my case.

**What I know?**

When we integrate openCV in application we can do ABI configuration in gradle that helps us to reduce the size according to architecture.

Comment: And what is your question ? What you have tried for ABI in gradle ?

Comment: in SDK case i did not add anything? Should i do the same thing that we do in Application? will it results to multiple SDKs like we get multiple apk!

Comment: if you are going to use large SDK as a part of your SDK, your SDK will be large. That's fact.

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko its true! is there any way we can make multiple sdk according to architecture!

Comment: does OpenCV provide such option? If it does - you can make same way providing your SDK with multiple parts. But in general - it makes no sense, as the limited desktop internet connections are about 10 years in past, and SDK size does not matter in current real world

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko i got you but integrating 24Mb sdk to clients app results to 54Mb app that what am concerned about! I just want glare and blur detection via openCV, is there any way i can get this only?

Comment: that's the app which has to be split for different ABIs, not the SDK

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194419/discussion-between-rohit-and-vladyslav-matviienko).

Answer (score 0):

Copy folders 'armeabi, armeabi-v7a(other architecture also)' from '\OpenCV-android-sdk\sdk\native\libs\' to your app/src/main/jniLibs/.

```
app
   |
   src
      |
     main
        |
        jniLibs
            |
            armeabi
            |   |
            |   your_lib_compiled_for_armeabi.so
            |
            armeabi-v7a
            |   |
            |   your_lib_compiled_for_v7a.so
            |
            x86
            |   |
            |   your_lib_compiled_for_x86.so
```